# gulp less not copying @import url line

Tags: html, import, gulp, less

I have a gulp build file that creates a file 'style.css' from a bunch of *.less files. No errors are generated. Everything is being copied into style.css EXCEPT the first line:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700");
```

This results in the fonts in the built app looking wrong. However, when I copy the above @import into style.css by hand, everything looks right. So I know the problem is the lack of the above @import in style.css.

I cannot figure out why the above line is not being included in the target css file when gulp creates it.

This is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('index:build1', ['index:clean'], function () {
   return gulp.src('src/less/style.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/styles/'))
});
```

This is my (edited) style.less, which is basically a bunch of @import lines that pull in all the individual *.less files. (Which is all working.)

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700");

// Color list
@color-navy-blue:#34495e;
@color-violet:#9b59b6;
<snip, for readability>

// Additional variables
@menu-width: 180px;
@main-transition: all 0.1s ease-out 0s;

// Import all styles
@import "margins.less";
@import "alerts.less";
@import "modal.less";
<snip, it's a long list>
```

I know the url is good because I can paste it into Chrome and it returns the expected result (a bunch of @font-face entries).

Why is that first @import line not being included in the target .css file? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I figured it out. The @import is getting lost in a subsequent call to gulp-clean-css. I am now working on how to prevent that... 

I will leave the question in case someone in the future has a similar problem.

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssimport

Comment: Thanks, @RandomUs1r! That looks like a good solution.

Comment: Ended up using npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssimport to expand the imports before the call to gulp-css-clean. This prevents the <at>import from getting lost. Thanks again, @RandomUs1r.